# change from insert to normal mode when switching to another tab?

Tags: vim, macvim

Say I have multiple tabs with multiple buffers in split screens.

When I am in edit mode in one buffer and switch to another tab (ctrl-pageDown), I am still in insert mode.

Is there a way to automatically switch to normal mode when changing tabs ?

Even better, is it possible to return to insert mode when coming back to the original buffer ?

Comment: You should use insert mode only for editing text. It is what Vim modality was designed for; stopped editing text - quit insert mode.

Comment: Greg's answer provides the simple "get out of insert mode". My answer provides the "even better" return-to-original-mode.

Comment: I couldn't agree with ZyX more. My answer was in order to answer the question. I would actually recommend that training yourself to leave insert mode as soon as you've made an edit will solve the problem for you. Besides gt is a lot quicker than using CTRL-pgdn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `BufLeave` you could call a function which would check what mode you're in and set a buffer variable and then in `BufEnter` check if it exists and go to that mode.

See help on `mode()`, `b:var`.

Here is some sample stuff for `.vimrc`. Having written it just now for this purpose, I've started using it myself and I think it'll be useful.

```
au BufLeave * call ModeSelectBufLeave()
au BufEnter * call ModeSelectBufEnter()

function! ModeSelectBufLeave()
    let b:mode_select_mode = mode()
    " A more complex addition you could make: if mode() == v, V, <C-V>, s, S, or <C-S>, store the selection and restore it in ModeSelectBufEnter
endfunction

function! ModeSelectBufEnter()
    let l:mode = mode()
    stopinsert  " First, go into normal mode
    if (l:mode == "i" || l:mode == "R" || l:mode == "Rv") && 
    \       (!exists('b:mode_select_mode') ||
    \       b:mode_select_mode == "n" ||
    \       b:mode_select_mode == "v" ||
    \       b:mode_select_mode == "V" ||
    \       b:mode_select_mode == "\<C-V>" ||
    \       b:mode_select_mode == "s" ||
    \       b:mode_select_mode == "S" ||
    \       b:mode_select_mode == "\<C-S>")
        normal l
        " Compensate for the left cursor shift in stopinsert if going from an
        " insert mode to a normal mode
    endif
    if !exists('b:mode_select_mode')
        return
    elseif b:mode_select_mode == "i"
        startinsert
    elseif b:mode_select_mode == "R"
        startreplace
    elseif b:mode_select_mode == "Rv"
        startgreplace
    endif
endfunction
```

Answer (score 7):

You could try adding something very simple like

```
autocmd TabEnter * stopinsert
```

to your .vimrc.

Comment: He'll want `BufEnter`, not `TabEnter`.

Answer (score 1):

I have the following in my .vimrc:

```
nmap <C-b> :b#<CR>
imap <C-b> <ESC>:b#<CR>
```

This lets me hit <kbd>Ctrl+b</kbd> when in normal or insert mode to switch to the alternate buffer but leaving me in normal mode.

As for your question, you could do this:

```
imap <C-b> <ESC>:bnext<CR>i
```

This will let you hit <kbd>Ctrl+b</kbd> when in insert mode and switch to the next buffer putting you in insert mode when you get there.

If you find yourself switching back and forth between the same two buffers, my original mappings above may be more useful.  Of course if you use all three, you'll need a different key combination for the last one.

Comment: You should use `inoremap`/`nnoremap` if you don't want to face strange problems as your number of vimrc mappings grows.

Comment: @ZyX - I think that'll only be a problem if I use `<C-b>` in the rhs of a mapping.  For example, I've remapped * to *N and in that case I used `noremap * *N`.  Nevertheless you make a valid point.  Thanks.

Comment: It will be a problem if you (for example) once realize that you want to use `;` for entering command mode and `:` for repeating inline search. Having an {lhs} in the {rhs} is not too problematic compared to having {lhs} of the other mapping in the {rhs}.